# How to use classification report from sklearn for keras models?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

So i have written a network which consists of the followings for multi-class classification :
-y_labels transformed with to_categorical
-last layer uses a sigmoid function with 3 neurons as my classes
-model compile uses  categorical_crossentropy as loss function
So i used

```
 model.predict_classes(x_test)
```

and then i used it as

```
   classification_report(y_test,pred)
```

y_test has the  form to_categorical
And i am getting the following error :

```
ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types set(['binary', 'multilabel-indicator'])
```

My question is how can i transform it back in order to use it as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error simply indicates that `y_test` and `pred` are of different types. Check function `type_of_target` in [multiclass.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L206-L229). As indicated here one of the `y` is indicator of classes and another of class vector. You can infer which one is what just by printing the shape, `y_test.shape , pred.shape`.

More over since you are using `model.predict_classes` instead of `model.predict` your output of `model.predict_classes` will be just classes and not class vector.

So either you need to convert one of them by:

```
# class --> class vector
from keras.utils import np_utils
x_vec = np_utils.to_categorical(x, nb_classes)

# class vector --> class 
x = x_vec.argmax(axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much from your comment. it was just a simple solution although it took me some time.  thanks again

Comment: No problem. Can you accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @indraforyou if you have a chance can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386561/keras-accuracy-is-different-between-model-predict-model-evaluate-and-classifica/