# Keras: Classification report accuracy is different between model.predict accuracy for multiclass

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Colab link is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pQFYKRio7JiE5UdteBu2QN9DKQZ3eHcJ?usp=sharing):

The data is imported the following was

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_folder,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="training",
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(dim, dim))

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_folder,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="validation",
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(dim, dim))
```

The model is trained the following way

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255),
    ...
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am struggling with getting the right `predicted categories` and right `true_categories` to get the classification report to work:

```
y_pred = model.predict(val_ds, batch_size=1)
predicted_categories = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0).numpy()
true_categories_argmax = np.argmax(true_categories, axis=1)

print(classification_report(true_categories_argmax, predicted_categories))
```

At the moment the output of the epoch is contradicting the classification report

```
Epoch 22/75
144/144 [==============================] - 7s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0611 - accuracy: 0.9776 - val_loss: 0.0768 - val_accuracy: 0.9765
```

The validation set on the model returns

```
model.evaluate(val_ds)

[==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0696 - accuracy: 0.9784
[0.06963862478733063, 0.9784313440322876]
```

while the classification report is very different:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support
     0.0       0.42      0.44      0.43       221
     1.0       0.56      0.54      0.55       289
    accuracy                           0.49       510
   macro avg       0.49      0.49      0.49       510
weighted avg       0.50      0.49      0.50       510
```

Similiar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973362/neural-network-my-networks-seems-like-is-training-well-but-at-classification), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341444/cannot-get-classification-report-even-after-rounding-up-predictions), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574431/how-to-use-classification-report-from-sklearn-for-keras-models), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56815476/very-good-validation-accuracy-but-bad-predictions), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738503/tensorflow-keras-in-a-multi-class-classification-accuracy-is-high-but-precis) with no answers to this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get classification report even after rounding up predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341444/cannot-get-classification-report-even-after-rounding-up-predictions)

Comment: @gobrewers14 I updated the question, please re-consider.

Comment: `true_categories[:,0]`. This is wrong.

Comment: If this is a multi-label classification then you need to round your predictions to get predicted labels, also loss should be `binary_crossentropy`. Another thing is if your data is multilabeled then you should not be able to load them with `image_dataset_from_directory`, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Frightera the output from `image_dataset_from_direcotory` says `Found 6457 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 5812 files for training.
Found 6457 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 645 files for validation.` So that is fine. Because inside that folder it has the two classes separated. Regarding your point can you please show an example of ` round ing the predictions to get predicted labels`?

Comment: @gobrewers14 can you please propose the right answer?

Comment: I think you are confusing **multi-label** with **multi-class** classification.

Comment: @Frightera my apologies this is a multi-class, it is either a car or a bicycle. Never both.

Comment: @gobrewers14 you basically voted the question to `close` and said what was wrong. Can you please propose the right answer then?

Comment: @JosephAdam I am more than willing to help you, but the issue you are having is not reproducible. It is completely dependent on your specific training and validation data. I don't have that data. It is difficult to fix a problem I cannot reproduce on my computer at home.

Comment: @gobrewers14 thanks for that. I have created a colab so you are able to see what I am seeing. Simply execute the whole notebook and you can see the `model.fit` contradicts the classification report https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pQFYKRio7JiE5UdteBu2QN9DKQZ3eHcJ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `label_mode='categorical'` then this is a **multi-class** classification and you need to use `softmax` activation in your last dense layer. Because softmax force the outputs sum to be equal to 1. You can kinda interpret them as probabilities. With `sigmoid` it will not be possible to find the **dominant** class. It can assign any values without restriction.

**My model's last layer**: `Dense(5, activation = 'softmax')`

**My model's loss**: `loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()`, same as yours. Labels are one-hot-encoded in this case.

**Explanation:**
I used a 5 class classification for demo purposes, but it follows the same logic.

```
y_pred = model.predict(val_ds)

y_pred[:2]
>>> array([[0.28257513, 0.4343998 , 0.18222839, 0.04164065, 0.05915598],
       [0.36404607, 0.08850227, 0.15335019, 0.21602921, 0.17807229]],
      dtype=float32)
```

This incidates each classes probabilities, for example first example has a probability of 43% being belong to class 2. You need to use `argmax` to find class index.

```
predicted_categories = np.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)
predicted_categories[:2]

array([1, 0])
```

We now have the predicted classes. Now need to obtain true classes.

```
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis = 0).numpy() # convert to np array

    true_categories[:2]
>>> array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

If you feed this into classification report, you will get following:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets
```

We need to also do:

```
    true_categories_argmax = np.argmax(true_categories, axis = 1)
    true_categories_argmax[:2]
>>> array([0, 4])
```

Now it is ready to for comparison.

```
print(classification_report(true_categories_argmax, predicted_categories))
```

That should produce the expected result:

```
      precision    recall  f1-score   support

   0       0.55      0.43      0.48       129
   1       0.53      0.83      0.64       176
   2       0.48      0.56      0.52       120
   3       0.75      0.72      0.73       152
   4       0.66      0.31      0.42       157
```

**Edit:** Classes might get shuffled as `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` sets `shuffle = True`. For `val_ds` try to set `shuffle = False`. Like this:

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_folder,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="validation",
    shuffle = False,
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(dim, dim))
```

**Edit2:** Here is what I came up with:

```
prediction_classes = np.array([])
true_classes =  np.array([])

for x, y in val_ds:
  prediction_classes = np.concatenate([prediction_classes,
                       np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis = -1)])
  true_classes = np.concatenate([true_classes, np.argmax(y.numpy(), axis=-1)])
```

**Classification Report:**

```
print(classification_report(true_classes, prediction_classes))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.74      0.81      0.77      1162
         1.0       0.80      0.72      0.75      1179

    accuracy                           0.77      2341
   macro avg       0.77      0.77      0.76      2341
weighted avg       0.77      0.77      0.76      2341
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I appreciate your time. One thing again, the classification report still shows a different error than the actual epoch. Please take a look at the .gif, updated part of the question. Every time I execute the line, the classification report shows me different accuracy values.

Comment: Minor differences might occur because of the batch_size when you execute predict(). As far as I see recall and precision values were nearly the same. Can you try with y_pred = `model.predict(val_ds, batch_size = 1)`? Also I guess your model is not trained, when you trained it properly, accuracy from classification report and `model.evaluate` should match with *minor differences*

Comment: @frightera there is `model.fit`. Can you please explain by `also I guess your model is not trained`. You cannot run `model.predict` without having `model.fit` ready

Comment: I missed it. Your accuracy is 0.50 in 2-class classification so it means your model is random guessing. That's why I thought it was not trained. I just tried 2 class classification and everything went fine with accuracy and classification report. What's your accuracy values when training?

Comment: @Frightera when I do `model.evaluate(val_ds)` I get `16/16 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0696 - accuracy: 0.9784`. Everytime I execute `print(classification_report(true_categories_argmax, predicted_categories))` I get a different answer. That is 0.50, 0.54, 0.65,0.30. Something is wrong with the classification report code. Can you please look at the `.gif` in the question?

Comment: @Frightera same problen. I think sklearn is not able to handle multi-class from tensorflow.

Comment: Sklearn can handle it. I am out of ideas as I can not reproduce this issue, everytime I get expected results even with 2-classes.

Comment: @Frightera here it is in colab code, I hope you are able to reproduce the issue. Simply, re-execute the whole notebook. Please make a copy to your drive and try to execute there so the original copy is always there. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pQFYKRio7JiE5UdteBu2QN9DKQZ3eHcJ#scrollTo=PALBXLpzBiq6

Comment: @Frightera yes, finally looks right! Can you please add small explanation?

Comment: I exactly do not know how Keras shuffled the data even with you set `shuffle = False` for the dataset. But the last approach seems the safest way iterate over a dataset.

Comment: Hi there... I'm having similar issues. In my case, I'm also using image_dataset_from_directory. 
My dataset contains 5k pics within 5 folders. With a split of 0.2 for val_ds it receives 1050 pics, nevertheless if I use shuffle = False, it just will take one of 5 classes in it, it's like taking the elements in order... And I need a full sample for my classification report... Any suggestion?

I'm here because using shuffle  = True I'm having heavy differences between model accuracy and classification report accuracy.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use `shuffle = True` then the dataset will be reshuffled in each iteration. The last iteration that I've suggested should work even with `shuffle = True`. You need to iterate over the dataset with: `for x, y in ds: ...` but your label mode should be `categorical`.

Answer (score 1):

I there, I was having the same issues and for me it wasn't enough to have a softmax layer and shuffle = False. In fact, setting shuffle = False in image_dataset_from_directory I had the following problem: train_ds had just 3 of 5 classes and val_ds had 2 of 5 classes (the split was done without creating heterogeneous samples)

If it helps, I was recommended to do the following:

- To make just 2 folders (regardless your number of classes): train folder and validation folder. They must contain a shuffled portion of the whole.
- Use the sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split with stratify parameter for labels to create the folders with heterogeneous sample.
- when calling image_dataset_from_directory, do not split it into train in validation, but calling different folders (the train folder and the validation folder), now both with shuffle = False.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I faced with the accepted answer here is the fact that my dataset was batched. One way around was to set batch_size to 1 in:

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    labels='inferred',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    label_mode='int',
    seed=1337,
    color_mode="rgb",
    image_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=1,
   # shuffle=True
)
```

and then fit the model as usual to get the classification report as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
y_true = []
y_pred=[]
for images, labels in val_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
    y_pred_probs = conv_model.predict(images, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred_probs, axis=1)
    y_true.extend(labels)
    y_pred.extend(y_pred_classes)

# Convert the true labels to class labels
#y_true_classes = np.argmax(y_true, axis=0)

# Generate a classification report
report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred)

print(report)
```

Hope this helps.